# RazorPage not calling PageModel function

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I can't get a button to call a function in the PageModel

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" asp-page-handler="ExecuteScraping" asp-route-servername="@(server.serverName)">Update All</button>
```

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetExecuteScrapingAsync(string servername)
            {
                await _controller.ExecuteScraping(servername);
                return RedirectToPage("Index");
            }
```

Also tried function names such as:

```
ExecuteScraping()
ExecuteScrapingAsync()
```

Seems like such an easy problem but can't get these 'other' functions thats not OnPostX or OnGetX to work.

Using .Net 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `<a>` tag.So that when click it will send a get request:

```
<a asp-page-handler="ExecuteScraping" asp-route-servername="@(server.serverName)">Update All</a>
```

If you want to send a post request,you can try to use form:

```
<form method="post">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" asp-page-handler="ExecuteScraping" asp-route-servername="testName">Update All</button>
</form>
```

handler:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostExecuteScrapingAsync(string servername)
            {
                await _controller.ExecuteScraping(servername);
                return RedirectToPage("Index");
            }
```